# How to define target ABI property in tiapp.xml in Appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

As I want to reduce my app size. So I got below suggestion from Appcelerator forum

> You can reduce this size depending on which Android API levels you
>   target.If you need to reduce size, You have to create two separate
>   apks for older (armeabi) and newer (armeabi-v7a) devices

So I want to remove for older (armabi). As Targeting an ABI architecture will help reduce the application and APK size

**How to define target ABI property in tiapp.xml in Appcelerator?**

While surfing on google I got below tag:

```
<property name="ti.android.abi">all</property> <!-- to support all devices -->
<property name="ti.android.abi">armabi, armabi-v7a</property> <!-- to support both old, new devices -->
<property name="ti.android.abi">armabi</property> <!-- to support old devices -->
<property name="ti.android.abi">armabi, armabi-v7a</property> <!-- to support new devices -->
```

After each of above trial I didn't got any change in memory size of apk file.

**Note:** I am building this app for android device

**Can anyone help on it ?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't have first-hand experience with it, but the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/tiapp.xml_and_timodule.xml_Reference-section-29004921_tiapp.xmlandtimodule.xmlReference-abi) suggests that it's not a property of ti.android.abi, but instead, it's an  element inside the android-specific section of your tiapp.xml.

For example:

`<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <abi>armabi</abi>
    </android>`

Note that you should understand the ramifications of not including support for all ABIs.  It's more than just reducing your app size.  Eliminating armabi-v7a could reduce performance for newer devices, and eliminating armabi means older devices can't run your app at all.

Comment: I tried it, but it is not working it seems. I kept it under <manifest></manifest> tag.

Comment: I don't think it goes under <manifest>.  Notice my example -- it goes directly under <android>.

Comment: I tried directly also, but it thrown some exception